# autorelease caused a system crash iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I have the method without ARC to read plist file content:

```
-(void)readAppFile
{
    NSString *plistPath = [self getDataFileDestinationPath];
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (!temp) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    }
    items = [[temp objectForKey:@"Items"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Read file!");
}
```

I have a great memory leak here! So I replace the end of the code with this line `items = [[[temp objectForKey:@"Items"] mutableCopy] autorelease];` but now I have `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, addres=0x6000000008)`. Today is the second day I don't know what to do with this method.

Comment: mem leak but where? plistPath, plistXML, format, temp, items...which one?

Comment: release `items`, not the whole `objectForKey:` thing

Comment: @AnoopVaidya items - this is the only one object which I have to release. But I don't understand - what's wrong with autorelease..

Comment: @CodaFi for me now it is rather difficult to understand where I have to release it.. It is global variable.. And I don't know exactly how to release it correctly - so I tried to add autorelease.. but crash

Comment: try sending `release` in dealloc.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya thanks, but the thing a little bit more complicated here, this is the method of the singleton class, and this class has 1 variable - items, with what I work through all the app. But in the instruments u can see the following https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15833199/5704.png Any ideas what can I do with this..

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly releasing `items` just before you reassign it:

```
if (items != nil) [items release];
items = [[temp objectForKey:@"Items"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: The `if (items != nil)` is redundant. Sending `-release` (or any other method) to `nil` is always safe.